# How to convert JAVASCRIPT CODE to Google Apps for Google Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How to convert javascript code into Google application (extension) for Google Chrome browser?

Comment: You need to add some more information to your question. There's no one way to do it, and often JS code has to be specifically written as an extension. To get started, have a look at [Extensionizr](http://extensionizr.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an extension, head here- http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index

You may have to rewrite some code to make it work as an extension as it's not the same as running in a browser.